# Window object containing variable property before declaration (with value)

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, hoisting

In following examle, how in world does first `window.object` (`console.log` first time) contain variable `a` that too with value '10'? As, there is no global function wrapping so concept of 'hoisting' does not occur, even if it occurs - `a` will be hoisted as value `undefined`.

I can understand second window object has property `a` as '10', but how can first window object before declaring and putting variable value as '10' still containing it. What is happening?

**Note:** 'StackOverflow' wraps the code in its own global function, so not running here.

```js
console.log(this);

var a = 10;

console.log(this);
```

**Outcome:**

[image]
[image]

**Note:** This code runs in 'chrome'.

Comment: Is this on chrome or firefox?

Comment: The code runs in 'chrome'.

Comment: as far as i can make out is while logging the objects are logged fine but. In console when you expand them for the first time they are evaluated the window object already have a reference to `a` so both the logs show it. instead try this log the first statement then check the logged object it wont have a. Then declare the variable and then log the object again now will see a in second log. And a wont be there in first log.

Comment: The property exists because it is hoisted. It has its value logged because the console expands the object lazily.